# Google PubSub batching increase by load balancing subscribers

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

From the documentation it's not quite clear whether the fact that the maximum batch size is 1000 messages, what it the optimal solution to increase beyong that the number of tasks being processed at any given time.

Is it possible and is it correct to create multiple Subscriber Clients for the same Subscription?

**Example:**
For **Subscription name "abc"** we set up **5 subscribers**, and then we run :

```
repeat(5000) {
    publisher.publish(msg)
}
```

Which one of these is correct :

1. Maximum 1,000 messages will be distributed between the 5 subscribers?
2. Each of the 5 subscribers will receive 1000 messages, and so they will all handle 5,000 tasks concurrently ?

Comment: What do you mean by "number of tasks being processed at any given time?" Do you mean on the subscribe side? Publish-side batching does not impact execution or distribution of messages to subscribers.

Comment: What I mean is that when I send 5000 tasks, I see logs printed in 1000 subscribers. Then, after several seconds, I see another 1000, ...  And I read that the maximum batch size is 1,000 so it kind of made sense. I just didn't understand whether that limit is on the publisher side or subscriber's

Comment: I meant *1000 logs printed in a single subscriber

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5000 messages published and multiple subscribers, each one will only be able to receive 1000 messages at a time if you have not overridden the [flow control settings](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/flow-control). By default, the Pub/Sub client library allows 1000 messages to be outstanding at a time. As messages are acked or nacked, more messages are delivered up to that 1000-message limit. If you need to be able to receive more messages without acknowledging ones that are already received (due to long processing time on messages), then you should increase the flow control limits.

The actual distribution of messages to subscribers has no guarantees. Generally, the load will be shared evenly among subscribers, though there are cases where that may not be true. For example, if you are using ordering keys and have some keys that receive more messages than others, then the balance of messages may skew toward subscribers assigned the keys with more messages.